# Enumerate emails in inbox and click all the links within the email

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a script that enumerates through all the emails within the outlook inbox and clicks all the links within all the emails. This is what I have so far and for testing I am only grabbing the first 10 emails with the `$emails` variable.

I think my problem is the `invoke-webrequest` because out of the 10 emails I have tested only 4 of them seem to have a successful invoked web request (at least in the powershell ISE it shows me a successful connection this is just showing the 200 response from the GET request).

So another question I have is even though the connection failed is it still reaching out to make a connection or is this issue part of the regex not storing some of the URL's correctly? I am testing some software that is suppose to alert on clicked links to known bad domains.

My third question is my `-match` regex I believe only matches the first regex URL link within an email and stores it within the matches hashtable. I would like it to match **ALL** links within an email, if anyone has an improvement to this please let me know.

```
# Build the inbox ingestion
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type] 

# Create a new Comobject which leverages the advantages of the COM 
# interfaces for system administration
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application

# Use the Microsoft Application Programming Interface
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
$emails = $folder.items | Select-Object Body | Select-Object -f 10 

# Build the empty Array to store url links
$URLArray = @()

# loop through all the emails within the inbox
foreach ($email in $emails) {
    # store a matched regex which is a url nd select the url from the stored hash table of $matches,
    # The values is a member of a method from the .NET framework
    $LinksEmail = $email -match "\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])"
    $values = $matches | select values

    # This is our first inner loop within the loop of email enumeration, at each email within the all emails loop this loop
    # will execute and store the values from the url matches hash table into a position within the
    # $URLArray array data structure
    foreach ($value in $values) {$URLArray += $value.values}
    # write-output $value.values
}

# this is not an inner loop but aloop after we have built our $URLArray array which uses a try-catch 
# block to attempt to invoke a web request which should be a stored url at each indexed position
# in the array
# write-output $URLArray
foreach ($item in $URLArray) {
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest -verbose $Item
        write-output "This was successful"
    }
    catch { write-output "This Failed $item"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you validate your regex?

This...

> $LinksEmail = $email -match

… will return only true or false for the very first match and stop.

```
$UrlList = @'
this is the URL https://stackoverflow.com/&20%
http://stackoverflow.com
http://www.SomeSite.com this is oure main site
http://www.SomeSite.com
ftp://www.somesite.com
ftp://somesite.com
ftp\SomeSite.com
If you want the file go there: file://SomeSite.com
'@
($values = $UrlList -match "\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])")
True

($values = $matches | select values)

Values
------
{https://stackoverflow.com/&20%}
```

Even with that, when I place it in Sapien's PowerRegEx tool, and populate several URL's, it does not get all of them, or only part of them. Format dependent of course

URL's are the base plus any string that follows it of course and you only want the base URL to check, and you are not handling that at all from what you show here.

Try this one and see if it helps. This one is grabbing the whole string not just the base, but that can be easily changed.

```
$UrlList = @'
this is the URL https://stackoverflow.com/&20%
http://stackoverflow.com
http://www.SomeSite.com this is our main site
http://www.SomeSite.com
ftp://www.somesite.com
ftp://somesite.com
ftp\SomeSite.com
If you want the file go there: file://SomeSite.com
'@ 

[RegEx]::Matches($UrlList, '(ftp:|ftp|http:|https:|file:)(//.([^\s]+)|\\.([^\s]+))').value

https://stackoverflow.com/&20%
http://stackoverflow.com
http://www.SomeSite.com
http://www.SomeSite.com
ftp://www.somesite.com
ftp://somesite.com
ftp\SomeSite.com
file://SomeSite.com
```

Comment: I validated my regex by testing it, you are correct that it only matches the first hit after further testing, I will test your suggestion thank you.

Comment: Okay so I have been trying to test your method, but your method is taking it from a raw pre made array, mine is trying to grab links while it is looping through the emails within the inbox. You think you could change your suggestion to the context of how I would use it because I have tried many attempts and I am unable to use your suggestion